# Objects seemingly not being passed by reference in C++

Tags: c++, reference, const-reference

Edit: The problem has been found to be that the Wrapper class is creating copies of the BSCallFunction when passed into the MCEngine function and in the SimulationEngine class shown below. With this in mind I still need to figure out how to make the program do what I want it to, as detailed in the question. The comment section contains the finding thus far.

```
class SimulationEngine
{
public:
    SimulationEngine(double horizon, const Wrapper<valuationFunction>& theFunction_, RiskFactor simulatedRiskFactor);
    virtual void DoOnePath(double vol, double normvariate) = 0;
    virtual SimulationEngine* clone() const = 0;
    const double GetHorizon();
    Wrapper<valuationFunction>& GetFunction();
    RiskFactor simulatedRiskFactor;
protected:
    double horizon;
    Wrapper<valuationFunction> theFunction;
};
```

In my main class I'm creating this object:

```
    BSCallFunction ThisBsCall(nominal, S0, r, d, impvol, TTM, Strike);
```

Which I'm passing into two classes (derived from the same base class) that will change some of its values (like S0 and r).

```
    OneStepBSEngine BSSimulation(timeHorizon, zeroDrift, ThisBsCall, RiskFactor::equity);
    OneStepBrownianMotionEngine ShortRateSimulation(timeHorizon, zeroDrift, ThisBsCall, RiskFactor::interest_rate);
```

I want both the two classes to change the value of the same object so that I end up with a ThisBsCall that has different r and S0.

The classes have this structure:

```
class OneStepBrownianMotionEngine : public SimulationEngine
{
public:
    OneStepBrownianMotionEngine(double horizon_, double drift_,const Wrapper<valuationFunction>& theFunction_, RiskFactor simulatedRiskFactor_);
    virtual SimulationEngine* clone() const;
    void DoOnePath(double vol, double normvariate);
private:
    double drift;
};

OneStepBrownianMotionEngine::OneStepBrownianMotionEngine(double horizon_, double drift_,const Wrapper<valuationFunction>& theFunction_, RiskFactor simulatedRiskFactor_) : SimulationEngine(horizon_, theFunction_, simulatedRiskFactor_), drift(drift_)
{
}
```

Where I'm passing the "ThisBsCall" object by const reference.

Back in my main class I will then create the object MCEngine and use the function that will change the values of r and S0 using the Engine classes above, the Enginevector is just a vector of the two Engine classes:

```
MCEngine VAREngine(EngineVector, covmat);
VAREngine.DoSimulation(gathererCombiner, NumberOfPaths);
```

I pass the enginevector by const reference as well like so:

```
MCEngine(const std::vector<Wrapper<SimulationEngine>>& EngineVector, std::vector<std::vector<double>> covMatrix_);
```

I'm not sure if it matters but the constructor and function used looks like this in the MCEngine class:

```
MCEngine::MCEngine(const std::vector< Wrapper<SimulationEngine>>& EngineVector_, std::vector<std::vector<double>> covMatrix_)
    : cholMatrix(Cholesky_Decomposition(covMatrix_)), EngineVector(EngineVector_), V(0)
{
}

void MCEngine::DoSimulation(StatisticsMC& TheGatherer, unsigned long NumberOfPaths)
{
    UpdateTTM();  
    double thisPortfolioValue;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < NumberOfPaths; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<Wrapper<SimulationEngine>> tmpEngineVector(EngineVector);  //save the origianl EngineVector to use on next path
        //create vector of correlated normal variats with cholezky decompositon
        MJArray corrNormVariates(cholMatrix.size());
        corrNormVariates = 0;
        MJArray NormVariates(cholMatrix.size());
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < cholMatrix.size(); i++)
        {
            NormVariates[i] = GetOneGaussianByBoxMuller();
            for (unsigned long j = 0; j < cholMatrix[i].size(); j++) {
                corrNormVariates[i] += cholMatrix[i][j] * NormVariates[j];
            }
            corrNormVariates[i] /= cholMatrix[i][i]; //normalize the random variates
        }
        //use each one for simulation with spotvector/volvector
        for (unsigned long j = 0; j < EngineVector.size(); ++j)
        {
            EngineVector[j]->DoOnePath(cholMatrix[j][j], corrNormVariates[j]); //updates the riskfactors for the positions
        }
        ValuePortfolio();
        thisPortfolioValue = GetPortfolioValue();
        TheGatherer.DumpOneResult(thisPortfolioValue);
        EngineVector = tmpEngineVector;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is when I look at the 2 BSCallFunction objects (which I expect to be the same ThisBsCall) they have different values for S0 and r, so it seems like at some point I copied the object and changed the value of r or S0 of this copy instead of the original and then returned the result. Is it possible to see where this might happen from what I've posted (or general advice on what I might be doing wrong)? I can post more of the code if it helps.

EDIT: The Wrapper class in case that might be what's causing issue:

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_H
#define WRAPPER_H
template< class T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper()
    {
        DataPtr = 0;
    }
    Wrapper(const T& inner)
    {
        DataPtr = inner.clone();
    }
    Wrapper(T* DataPtr_)
    {
        DataPtr = DataPtr_;
    }
    ~Wrapper()
    {
        if (DataPtr != 0)
            delete DataPtr;
    }
    Wrapper(const Wrapper<T>& original)
    {
        if (original.DataPtr != 0)
            DataPtr = original.DataPtr->clone();
        else
            DataPtr = 0;
    }
    Wrapper& operator=(const Wrapper<T>& original)
    {
    if (this != &original)
    {
    T* newPtr = (original.DataPtr != 0) ?
    original.DataPtr->clone() : 0;
    if (DataPtr != 0)
    delete DataPtr;
    DataPtr = newPtr;
    }
    return *this;
    }

        T& operator*()
    {
        return *DataPtr;
    }
    const T& operator*() const
    {
        return *DataPtr;
    }
    const T* const operator->() const
    {
        return DataPtr;
    }
    T* operator->()
    {
        return DataPtr;
    }
private:
    T* DataPtr;
};
#endif
```

Comment: It looks like you are passing a `const Wrapper<BSCallFunction> &` not a `const BSCallFunction &`  If a temporary object is being built for each call, that might explain the difference you are seeing.

Comment: Do you mean it might be built because of the Wrapper class? I edited the post with the class, can you see if that could be the case?

Comment: The wrapper class is cloning the object. See `Wrapper(const T& inner)`

Comment: Is there a simple solution to this? I didn't write the Wrapper class myself so I'm not exactly sure how it works it just seemed to fill my purposes

Comment: If you use the pointer constructor for the wrapper class, it will not copy but use the original object.  `OneStepBSEngine BSSimulation(timeHorizon, zeroDrift, &ThisBsCall, RiskFactor::equity);` To be honest though, you need to understand what this class is doing before you try changing things.

Comment: That triggers a breakpoint on  ~Wrapper() at  delete DataPtr;

Comment: That makes sense.`ThisBSCall` appears to be on the stack. Not having called new, delete would be a problem.  As the SimulationEngine class (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61896004/how-to-make-an-enum-recognized-by-other-classes) is using a copy of the Wrapper any way, passing the object now, then changing it later is not going to work.

Comment: Yes I noticed that as well when debugging, that using &ThisBsCall indeed calls the pointer constructor but that Wrapper(const T& inner) is called later on anyway in SimulationEngine like you said. Do you have suggestions or ideas on how I could achieve my desired outcome? Or have I painted myself into a corner here? Thank you for looking into this with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that the `Wrapper` class is creating multiple copies of the `BSCallFunction` object.

For example:

```
BSCallFunction ThisBsCall(nominal, S0, r, d, impvol, TTM, Strike);
OneStepBrownianMotionEngine ShortRateSimulation(timeHorizon, zeroDrift, ThisBsCall, RiskFactor::interest_rate);
```

In the line above, a temporary `Wrapper` object is created and passed into constructor of `OneStepBrownianMotionEngine`, which makes a clone of the inner object and stores a pointer to it. Then this cloned object is passed to the base class `SimulationEngine`, which stores a copy of it using the copy constructor of the `Wrapper` class.

So 1 temporary object + another copy.

This happens likewise for the other engine class `OneStepBrownianMotionEngine`.

> Now my problem is when I look at the 2 BSCallFunction objects (which I
>   expect to be the same ThisBsCall) they have different values for S0
>   and r, so it seems like at some point I copied the object and changed
>   the value of r or S0 of this copy instead of the original and then
>   returned the result.

They will never be the same because the `Wrapper` class is designed to clone the object passed to it. You could create the `ThisBsCall` on the heap (`new BSCallFunction(...)`) and use the pointer. This will ensure the same `ThisBsCall` is used by both engines.

However, as you've discovered, this will cause a problem when the engines are destroyed: the destructor of `Wrapper` tries to delete the same `ThisBsCall` object. A double delete invariably leads to a crash!

What you what is for your `Wrapper` to:

- use a pointer to `ThisBsCall` so that you don't make a copy of it
- maintain a reference count for each shared owner of a `Wrapper` object
- destroy the `ThisBsCall` object when the reference count goes down to zero

[`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) does all this for you and it's part of the standard library. So I would recommend you use this instead of your `Wrapper` class. It will require the least amount of changes.

Your code could stay the same except you replace instances of

```
Wrapper<your_class_name>
```

with

```
std::shared_ptr<your_class_name>
```

For example:

```
std::shared_ptr<valuationFunction> ThisBsCall = std::make_shared<BSCallFunction>(nominal, S0, r, d, impvol, TTM, Strike);
```

The beauty of [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) like `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` is that they will take care of the memory management for you. You don't have to worry about manually calling `new` and `delete`. All that is done for you in the background. Plus they give you exception safety too. If for whatever reason an exception is thrown during memory allocation, the memory is cleared up for you. For these reasons and more this is why the recommended practice nowadays is to use smart pointers instead of doing the memory management ourselves.

I don't know if you're coding in a multithreaded environment? Although the control block that stores the managed object and the reference counter is thread-safe, a smart pointer per se isn't. You would still have to provide your own thread synchronization.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've heard about smart pointers before but never used them but this definitely makes sense. Thinking about it now I'm guessing the Wrapper class is in a way a smart pointer of it's own? Do you think I should try to get rid of the Wrapper class entirely in my code to "modernize" it? I.e, is there any situation where you would ever use something like this instead of one of the STL smart pointer? The book I'm using to learn about this was written in 2002 so maybe it's a bit outdated on the subject.

I'll be honest in saying that I don't know what a multithreaded environment.

Comment: @Oscar For your intended purpose of using the same `BSCallFunction` object in both engines a `std::shared_ptr` is ideal. Whoever designed the `Wrapper` class wanted to ensure they were working with a clone of the original object. Hence the problems you were having. This is a good example of why you should use a smart pointer. They came into the C++ standard with C++11. Before that you either that to implement one yourself or use `boost::shared_ptr`. If you are implementing it yourself and you don't get it right, then you could have a lot of memory problems.

Comment: Thank you, I feel then it would probably be a good learning experience for me to try to get rid of the other mentions of Wrapper in my program as well and find suitable smart pointers that do the same